# How to avoid datastore_v3.Next calls

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

My datastore processing takes lot of times.
So, I checked what process takes time with StackDriver -> Trace.
Then, "datastore_v3.Next" is called many times.

I found following document.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appstats

> Datastore queries usually involve a datastore_v3.RunQuery followed by
>   zero or more datastore_v3.Next calls. (RunQuery returns the first few
>   results, so the API only uses Next when fetching many results.
>   Avoiding unnecessary Next calls may speed up your app!)

But, I don't understand

- In what cases will datastore_v3.Next be called many time?
- How to avoid Next calls?

Add:
MyCode is below

```
    @classmethod
    def get_foo(cls, user_key, foo):
      search_key = ndb.Key('UserInformation', user_key.id(), 'Foo', foo)
      return search_key.get()
```

UserInformation and Foo kind have 1 million entity.

Comment: Iterating through a query object calls Next, which is typical a use pattern. Can you provide the code for the call you traced?

Comment: thx.I add my code.

Comment: Are you getting entities in a loop in any portion of your code?

Comment: not in a loop. But it is called many times via Mapreduce

Comment: Can you provide more information, more scope, especially the MapReduce part? Code?

Answer (score 0):

The primary way is the one mentioned in [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appstats), simply don't return an unnecessarily large result set.

If you only care about the first few results in the query, you can look into using [fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_fetch) which can return a limited set of results instead of the whole thing.

In addition, you can also make good use of [memcache on NDB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/cache#memcache), less datastore calls means less .Next calls overall.